# Syntax error at `fi' after 'else'

Tags: shell

I am getting this error when I try to run my shell script:

> ERROR: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

The script is:

```
case $# in
0) echo Usage is: $0 filename [filename]
  exit;;
*);;
esac

for i in $*
do
   if test -f $i;
   then
      echo $i
      cat $i
   else
fi
done
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: paste your code in http://www.shellcheck.net and see errors

Comment: @Rahul, good advice, though shellsheck is missing a few like `echo` -> `printf`, errors should go on stderr, should exit non-zero on error, `cat < "$i"` instead of `cat $i`...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's mostly the kind of issues that I think we can only infer based on context, and computers are, as we know, rather poor at establishing context...

Answer (score 3):

[As schily already mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302303/2465), a bash shell script (which this looks distinctly like) does not allow empty blocks between `if` and either `else`, `elif` or `fi`, or between `else` or `elif` and the corresponding `fi`. (This comes down to: each conditional must *do* something.)

**You can either delete the `else` statement, or, if you want it for later, place a dummy command within the `else` block.** For example, you could rewrite your script to read:

```
case $# in
0) echo Usage is: $0 filename [filename]
  exit;;
*);;
esac

for i in $*
do
   if test -f $i;
   then
      echo $i
      cat $i
   else
      true
   fi
done
```

(I also indented the `fi` to match the `if`. That's a matter of style, but I personally find it much easier to read that way.)

`true` has as its sole purpose to return a successful exit status, but it is a command, so this script will do nothing if the name in `$i` does not refer to a simple file (`test -f`).

Answer (score 1):

Empty commands are not allowed, so simply remove the `else` line.